# Changing leaflet map with new one when the user has reached the endpoint

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I am using Leaflet Map and in this map there is a start point and end point the User have to drag the marker from the start point (red circle) to the end point (blue circle). when the User reach the end point I want to display a new Leaflet Map where the User have to drag again the marker from a start point to end point, let's imagine we have 8 different Maps(map1.js, map2.js...map8.js) and every map is different from the other. how and what is the best way to change the map with a new one when the user has reached the endpoint? how to call a `map1.js` and `map2.js` every time the user has reached the endpoint?

Here is my `map.js` code:

```js
var socket = io("ws://localhost:5501");

        const value = "Hello, server!";
        socket.emit("message", value);

        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");


        output.innerHTML = slider.value;
        

        slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
        
        
        var slidervalue=parseInt(output.innerHTML);
        var slidertoservo=maprange(slidervalue,52,1275,0,180);
        
        socket.emit('servoposition', { "status":slidertoservo.toString() });
        }
        

        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.55, 9.99], 6);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        map.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen());

        var marker=L.marker([53.556130, 9.99818],{draggable:true}).bindPopup();
       
        marker.addTo(map);
         // START POINT 
        var circle1 = L.circle([53.556130, 9.99818], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 6000
        }).addTo(map);
        // END POINT 
        var circle2 = L.circle([47.3982, 11.11831], {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: '#5f1ee3',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 6000
        }).addTo(map);
        marker.addTo(map);


        marker.on('drag', getElevation);
                  
        function getElevation(){
          var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
       
        const api_url='http://localhost:5000/v1/test-dataset?locations='+latlng.lat+','+latlng.lng;
        
        const response= fetch(api_url).then(response => response.json()).then((data)=>{document.getElementById('markerelevationvalue').innerHTML = data.results[0].elevation;
        
        if(data.results[0].elevation>=0){
      
                
            var servominouput= maprange(parseInt(slider.value),52,1275,0,180);
            
            var minoutput=parseInt(servominouput);  
            
            
            var servodegree=maprange(data.results[0].elevation,52,1275,minoutput,180);
            servodegree=parseInt(servodegree);    
             
            socket.emit('servoposition_elevation', { "status":servodegree.toString() });
        } else{}
        
        });
        
         
        }

        function maprange(value,min1,max1,min2,max2){
          return((value-min1)*(max2-min2))/(max1-min1)+min2;
        }
```

And here is my HTML Page where I am calling `map.js`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Communicating from Node.js to an Arduino</title>
        
        
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.6.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-xbQU0+iHqhVt7VIXi6vBJKPh3IQBF5B84sSHdjKiSccyX/1ZI7Vnkt2/8y8uruj63/DVmCxfUNohPNruthTEQA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
       <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script> 
      
       <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
       <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />
       

       <style>
        .slidecontainer {
          width: 50%;
          padding-left: 200px;
        }
        
        .slider {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          width: 50%;
          position: fixed;
          height: 25px;
          background: #d3d3d3;
          outline: none;
          opacity: 0.7;
          -webkit-transition: .2s;
          transition: opacity .2s;
        }
        
        .slider:hover {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
          width: 25px;
          height: 25px;
          background: #04AA6D;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
          width: 25px;
          height: 25px;
          background: #04AA6D;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
 #infoPanel {
  /*float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
  #map {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    top: 113px;
  /*width: 1200px;
  height: 1000px;
  float: left;*/
  }
  
  /* 
   * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
   */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    touch-action: none;
  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

       
        <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="52" max="1275" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>  
        <div id="infoPanel">
          <b>elevation value:</b>
          <div id="markerelevationvalue"><i>drag the marker to see the elevation value.</i></div>
          <b>User hint:</b>
          <div id="info"></div>
          
        </div>

        
       <script src="map.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

does any one have an idea how to load a new Map every time when the user has reached the end point in the map?